# Adding a run configuration in PyCharm for a python project

Tags: python, pycharm, config

I opened a series of files to edit them and my run button is greyed out. I can't figure out exactly why, but I think it has something to do with the *"add configuration"* prompt nest to the run button. I don't know how to add a configuration and don't want to mess up my editor. I have the newest version of the community version of PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Add Configuration is greyed out because maybe you haven't added python path to the project try adding it and you should be clear before posting questions maybe some code and pictures will help. Try this and let me know if this have solved your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).